# Ruby and Redmine with Lighttpd: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, redmine, lighttpd

I got that error when I try to run redmine with lighttpd

/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)

Yes I know, that question has been asked already and that the answer was always "install bundler" and "bundle install", but I have done that. I installed bundler installed all required gems and ran bundler exec rake db:migrate and so on. I still get that error when trying to start lighttpd.

```
 # cd /srv/http/redmine
 # bundle install
 ...
 Using <various gems>
 Your bundle is complete!
 Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
 Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
 # ruby --version
 ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-linux]
 # gem --version
 2.0.0
 # rake --version
 rake, version 10.0.4
 # bundle --version
 Bundler version 1.3.5
```

I am running archlinux and that's not the first webserver I set up with arch, however the first attempt with ruby and lighttpd. I can not use unicorn or webrick, because I need SSL for redmine...

Answer (score 0):

If you need SSL, use nginx with unicorn or puma or even webrick in upstream.

Comment: Do you have any howto for this?

Comment: This sounds not like it is working out of the box... how do I use that? I have no clue about ruby, I am setting servers up, I do not develop them. I wonder why no one knows an answer to my problem. I did not only ask here, also in the redmine and the archlinux forum. This is the only answer I got. WHY is it so difficult to get a simple ROR application running???

Comment: It's not hard to run, it's just unusual to start with lighttpd. Everyone are using nginx+unicorn or apache+passenger and you ask those people about another solution which actually use by 0.000001%. Nothing will work "out of the box", if you administrating linux servers you must know this rule.

Comment: Another hint for solving your problem: You actually setup webserver + ssl support. And set listener for upstream. You don't even need to know something about ruby. Just setup webserver + ssl. After that programmers can run unicorn, puma, thin whatever and just point to exact port you will define in your webserver. Thats all.

Comment: Well actually not ssl is my problem, but that lighttpd won't start with redmine. I wanted to know why. I thought it should be possible to use lighttpd (wich I wanted to use instead of bloadware apache), because even lighttpd uses redmine: http://redmine.lighttpd.net/

Comment: I can only suggest using nginx as bulletproof solution. For lighttpd try first of all to rollback on ruby 1.9. Because of http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/37486 better do not use Ruby 2.0

Comment: I installed debian now and running lighttpd with the deb package of redmine. It works with that. Still no luck getting it to run with archlinux